# Ajax call route laravel not found

Tags: laravel

i want to make delete confirmation laravel with Modal, 
i call route laravel in ajax, but why the route is not found .

this is my route in laravel

```
Route::delete('delete-product/{productId}', 'StoreController@hapus')->name('product.delete');
```

this is my ajax delete..

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
        $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('productId'));
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
        productId = $('#id_delete').val();
    });
    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.hapus', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'delete-product/' + productId,
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
```

when i click icon trash,, modal is show, but in modal when i click delete button then inspect element in browser my route is not found

this is inspect element

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/delete-product/
    Request Method: DELETE
    Status Code: 404 Not Found
    Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

why the URL just **delete/product** .... not include ID ,,
even though my url in ajax called like this

```
......
  url: 'delete-product/' + productId,
.....
```

this is my blade code

```
    @if(sizeof($resp->content) > 0)
    <ul class="the-product">
        @foreach($resp->content as $item)
            <li>
                @if(isset($store) && $store->storeId == $item->store->storeId)
                <a href="#" class="like"><i class="icofont-ui-love"></i></a>
                @else
                <a class="btn btn-danger delete-modal"><i class="fa fa-trash" data-id="{{$item->productId}}"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return myFunction();" href="{{url('edit.product', $item->productId)}}"><i class="icofont-ui-edit"></i></a>
                {{-- <a href="edit-product/{{$item->productId}}" class="icon-product"><i class="icofont-ui-edit"></i></a> --}}
                {{-- <a href="{{route('product.delete',$item->productId)}}" class="icon-product"><i class="icofont-ui-delete"></i></a> --}}
                @endif
                {{-- onclick="ajaxContent(event, this);" --}}
                <a href="productDetail/{{ $item->productId }}" class="the-item @if($item->discount > 0)on-promo @endif">

                    @if($item->discount > 0)
                        <div class="prod-rib">{{ $item->discount }}% Off</div>
                    @endif
                    <img data-src="@if($item->imageId != null){{ config('constant.showImage').$item->imageId }}@else{{ asset('images/no-image-available.png') }}@endif"
                        src="@if($item->imageId != null){{ config('constant.showImage').$item->imageId }}@else{{ asset('images/no-image-available.png') }}@endif"
                        alt="{{ $item->productNm }}">
                    <div class="prod-name">{{ $item->productNm }}</div>
                    <div class="prod-rev">
                        @for($i=0; $i<5;$i++)
                            @if($i<$item->reviewRate)
                            <img src="{{asset('img/kopi-on.svg')}}" />
                            @else
                            <img src="{{asset('img/kopi.svg')}}" />
                            @endif
                        @endfor
                        <span>{{ $item->reviewCount }} ulasan</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prod-price">
                            @if($item->discount > 0)
                            <span>Rp. {{ number_format($item->price,0,',','.') }}</span> Rp. <i>{{ APIHelper::discountPrice($item->discount, $item->price) }}</i>
                            @else
                            Rp. <i>{{ APIHelper::discountPrice($item->discount, $item->price) }}</i>
                            @endif
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="add-cart" onclick="addToCart({{ json_encode($item) }})">Add to cart <i class="icofont-cart"></i></a>
                {{-- //onclick="ajaxContent(event, this);" --}}
                <a href="{{url('/store-detail/'.$item->store->storeId)}}"  class="the-store">
                    <img src="@if($item->store->storePic != null){{ config('constant.showImage').$item->store->storePic }}@else{{ asset('images/no-image-available.png') }}@endif" />
                    {{ $item->store->storeNm }}
                    <span>{{ $item->store->percentFeedback }}% ({{ $item->store->totalFeedback }}
                            feedback)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled">
            <span><i class="icofont-rounded-double-left"></i></span>
        </li><li class="disabled">
            <span><i class="icofont-rounded-left"></i></span>
        </li>
        {{-- active --}}
        @for ($i = 0; $i < $resp->totalPages && $i < 5; $i++)

        <li class="" onclick="ajaxContent(event, this,null,{'key':'page','value':{{$i+1}} })">
            <span>{{$i + 1}}</span>
        </li>
        @endfor
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="icofont-rounded-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="icofont-rounded-double-right"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
@else
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="style-msg errormsg mt-5">
            <div class="sb-msg"><i class="icon-remove"></i><strong>Maaf</strong>, pencarian anda tidak cocok dengan
                produk apapun. Silahkan coba lagi
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif

    <!-- Modal form to delete a form -->
    <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete the following post?</h3>
                    <br />
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_delete" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="title_delete" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hapus" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
            $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
            $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('productId'));
            $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
            productId = $('#id_delete').val();
        });
        $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.hapus', function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: 'delete-product/{productId}',
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                    $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
                    $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                        $(this).html(index+1);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

how to write URL in ajax ?
plis HELP..

Comment: Can you share your blade code ?

Comment: have been add on above

Comment: Did you log `productId` to the console inside the function that is making ajax call? Does it show there?

Comment: please try to run manual your ajax request with this for ex. delete-product/3 to see if it is working. if it is delete the product with id 3 that means that something is wrong with your productId that you pass to your ajax request. if not then somenthing else is wrong. like routes for example

Answer (score 1):

In your case, in the following code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
    $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
    $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('productId'));
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    productId = $('#id_delete').val();
});
```

`ProductId` is a local variable having scope function scope. You can not refer it outside unless you declare it globally at the top.

When you try to refer it directly later, it will not be having any value(undefined).

Secondly, You need to change

`url: 'delete-product/{productId}'`

with

`url: '/delete-product/' + productId,`

So below is the code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
        $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('productId'));
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.hapus', function() {

        var productId = $('#id_delete').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/delete-product/' + productId,
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
                $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).html(index+1);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```